# Pandas: assign values based on a previously unknown number of conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a function that receives a DataFrame, and a dictionary of column name, operator, and threshold.

Function looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df["passed_thresholds"] = False
threshold_dict = {"height": (operator.lt, 0.7), "width": (operator.gt, 0.1)}
def my_func(df, threshold_dict):
    # return df with "passed_thresholds" equal true for rows that meet the thresholds.
```

What I want to do is to find all the rows in `df` that meet the thresholds in `threshold_dict` and set the "passed_thresholds" column to be True for those rows only. Usually I can do this pretty easily with:

```
df.loc[(df["height"] < 0.7) & (df["width"] > 0.1), "passed_thresholds"] = True
```

But the issue here is that I won't know how many elements will be inside of threshold_dict and what their values will be. By the way, threshold_dict is flexible and I can change how it looks/works if you have a better idea for it too. For example, maybe passing in a operator function isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `concat` with for loop then apply `all`

```
out = pd.concat([y[0](df[x],y[1]) for x, y in threshold_dict.items()],axis=1).all(1)
df['passed_thresholds'] = out
```